# Pass Collection from view using Data-

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to append a Dictionary from my partial view as a data- element

VIEW

```
@using xxx.Helpers
@model xxx.xxx.xxx.AcronymsViewModel

@{
    var permissions = AuthHelper.GetPermissions;
 }

  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil hand record-list-item" title="Edit" data-controller="xxx" data-detailsview="xxx" data-applicationid="0" data-recordid="@record.Id" data-permissions="@permissions()" />
```

AuthHelper.GetPermissions is a dictionary declared as: Dictionary< string, Boolean>().

In my jQuery method I'd like to parse the permissions data- property so I can restrict html based on the page level permissions. Do I need to pass the dictionary as a JSON string?

```
 $(document).on('click', '.record-list-item', function () {
            try {
                var controller = $(this).data('controller');
                var detailsView = $(this).data('detailsview');
                var applicationId = $(this).data('applicationid');
                var recordId = $(this).data('recordid');
                var permissions = $(this).data('permissions');

              //PARSE permissions here. How can I do this?
}
catch (ex) {
                common.LoadError('Error Ocrrured, ex);
 }
});
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do but just in case let me give you an advice: you must NOT handle permissions on client code since anyone with minimal development knowledge can hack it.

Comment: Permissions are handled on the server side as well. But to be able to restrict the HTML view from loading (in jQuery UI Dialog) I'd like to check the permissions and disable the Save button unless the user had Admin rights. Authorize is setup on the sever to restrict the methods from firing. I'd like the UI to reflect that as well, even though a savy user could tweak the jQuery/JavaScript to re-enable it.

Comment: Good, as long a you're checking server side everything is good. Just wanted to raise the flag.

Comment: Understood. This is a non issue for Partial Views, it's only an issue when I need to load jQuery UI dialogs, but still want to control the buttons on the dialog form.